# MVC3: Apply Gaussian blur on a text box or text

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, blur, gaussian

I need to hide information when we ask user to verify it. For example re-entering the email address. I am asked to apply gaussian blur to achieve it. How could I achieve it in MVC3?

I am open to other options for hiding information too.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are actually trying to "hide" information you should not use a simple display trick.  If you are just trying to use a display trick I would suggest a retag to include CSS and eliminate MVC3.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Your client is running on a different computer in a different geographical area, and you have no real control over what the client does.  Even if you figured out a way to do it on one client, it doesn't mean all clients will do it.  What's more, all it takes is a simple right click and view source to see the actual information.

What you need to do is replace the information with **** or similar after it has been posted.